# hide navigationbar of uisearchdisplaycontroller when other viewcontroller is pushed

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

i have a uitableviewcontroller with uisearchdisplay controller. tapping on table cell pushes another view with some content and hides the navigationbar in the pushed view controller. the view controller has it's own uitoolbar, so far everything ok. the problem is that when a search result is shown and then tapping on the table cell view pushes the viewcontroller with uitoolbar with a navigation bar above it. so two bars on the pushed view. i dont want the navigation bar to be hidden. this code works if the viewcontroller is not pushed from search result

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

what i'm missing using uisearchdisplay controller and hiding its navigation bar when other view is pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have redesigned my app. i dont use uisearchdisplay controller. instead i use uisearchbar and tableview which works perfectly.